# How to Convert data:font to .ttf Font Format in CSS Font Face

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have a css font family like below(I have shorten it because of displaying limit otherwise it is much much bigger than what I have present here)
now can you please let me know that if there is a way to convert the `url()`content inti .ttf font formats or other standard font formatS ?

```
@font-face{font-family:'web_font';
 src:url('data:font/opentype;base64,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');}
```

Comment: There are lots of online services where you can input your base64 encoded stuff. Or is that not what you want? Also, opentype is not the same as .ttf. Well, it _can_ be, but it doesn't have to be!

Answer (score 2):

**1)  First of all you need to save the base64 string as a file.**

Some of the online service is restricted to how much you can enter, so simple do this locally by just opening the base64 string in your browser and you will be promoted with `save as` dialog, choose any name you want

Alternative (if the browser don't allow you to enter such a long url) create a download link open the page in any supported browser that supports download attribute (chrome, firefox, opera)

```
<a href="data:font/opentype;base64,d09GRVE8AAH..." download="web_font">download web_font</a>
```

**2) Then <s>you need</s> to figure out what file extension it's**

With just the small amount of base64 string you provided me i was able to recognize it as a woff file, by looking at it with a hex/text editor. I uploaded the saved file to https://hexed.it and could read in the beginning that it said [woff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Open_Font_Format)

So now you have your web_font.woff file!

**3) Convert it to TTF with the right tool for the woff - format**

[I can google that for you](http://bfy.tw/1P4q) and found for example [fontforge](http://fontforge.github.io) that dose this and some free online service as well.

[onlinefontconverter.com](https://onlinefontconverter.com) makes a good job at converting unknown formats by looking at the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) instead of the file extension so you can have your ttf file directly. And you don't have to install any program either. But it doesn't tell you what the original file extension is.

Comment: [It appears](https://github.com/jimmywarting/ofc) you are affiliated with onlinefontconverter.com. Please note that our [self-promotion policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497) requires you to disclose this information in answers like this one.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do this? If you have an actual font file, like a `.ttf` file, just *use that in your CSS*.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: WhateverNameYouNeed;
  src: url('location/to/your/file.ttf') format('truetype')
}
```

aaaaaand we're done. For universal acceptance, wrap it as a WOFF and then use that instead of the ttf OpenType font file, so that every modern browser supports it.

**NOTE:** you can't just blatantly convert your fonts, though. If you do not own the rights to the font, or the font does not come with a license that says derivatives are allowed, **you are not allowed to convert this font**.